# Unable to install pyocd in latest version of Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3, pyocd

I'm trying to set up our usual Anaconda development environment on a new Windows 10 PC. I downloaded the latest version of Anaconda last week (version 2023.09, I believe), and I'm having trouble installing pyocd. pyocd installed easily on all the other PCs several months ago.

I ran conda using Anaconda Powershell Prompt in administrator mode. Here's what conda returns:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda install -c conda-forge pyocd
>> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed                                                                                                               /

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

The error messages are pretty unhelpful - I'd try installing downrev packages, but I don't know which ones to downgrade. Any ideas what's going on?

*UPDATE*
I updated conda, and now it actually gives me actionable error messages:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda install -c conda-forge pyocd
>> Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
 - anaconda Platform: win-64 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: | warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package pyocd-0.34.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 requires cmsis-pack-manager >=0.4.0,<1.0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs  The following packages are incompatible 
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires  
│  └─ python 3.11.* , which can be installed; 
└─ pyocd is not installable because it requires 
   └─ cmsis-pack-manager >=0.4.0,<1.0  but there are no viable options
      ├─ cmsis-pack-manager 0.4.0 would require
      │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
      ├─ cmsis-pack-manager 0.4.0 would require
      │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
      ├─ cmsis-pack-manager 0.4.0 would require
      │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
      └─ cmsis-pack-manager 0.4.0 would require
         └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I'm a python/anaconda noob, so I don't know what to do with this info (yet), but I'm continuing to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dependency unavailable for Python 3.11 or later

Although the `pyocd` package is technically `noarch` (i.e., independent of Python version), it depends on `cmsis-pack-manager`, which has [failed to be rebuilt for Python 3.11+](https://github.com/conda-forge/cmsis-pack-manager-feedstock/pull/3). It would be encouraging to maintainers to comment on that Pull Request to voice your desire that this be built. Or if, you have insight into why it fails, contribute a PR.

Otherwise, you'll need to instead install the package in a Python 3.10 or earlier environment. For example,

```bash
conda create -n py310 -c conda-forge python=3.10 pyocd
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried downgrading to 3.11.0 yesterday, which gave me 3.11.0.final.0. I assume that's uprev from 3.11.0.0a0 (the highest recommended version), 'cause it's not working. I attempted to downgrade to 3.10.13, but it's been stuck in "solving environment" for the last 16 hours or so. I assume that's a failure. I'll try your suggested command now.

Thanks again!

Comment: One should almost never attempt changing Python versions in place. Create a new environment. If this is **base**, you shouldn't be installing `conda-forge` packages in Anaconda **base**, full stop. Ideally, **base** should be minimal and if you plan to require Conda Forge packages, then Miniforge makes the most sense. You can also try installing Anaconda with Python 3.10 (from the installer), but I strongly recommend against Anaconda + Conda Forge.

Comment: OK, I'll blow the whole install away and start over. Looks like I have some research to do around conda vs. conda-forge vs. miniforge and how to properly set up our environments. I've just been blindly following the instructions I find online for how to install various packages, which invariably say to just run "conda install xxxxxxx".

Comment: Thanks @merv, I now know a lot more about managing my Anaconda environment!